# Process Builder - Insert Record - Read Data Back From Record

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, administration, visual-workflow

**Is there a way using ONLY Process Builder to do this?**

- Insert a record #9991 into **ObjectX**
- Read field "**alpha__c**" from record #9991 *after the insert is complete*

Field "**alpha__c**" will contain some results produced by Apex after record #9991 is saved.  I need to read it right after the save is done, to know what happened.  I have no control over **ObjectX** or field "**alpha__c**" - I can insert, and I can query.  *[Managed Package]*

I know I can do this **in a Flow**.

I am trying to keep things at a low enough level for easy maintenance by non-technical people.  Flows are not as straightforward to teach to "Assistant Admins".

I've asked several Questions along these same basic lines - making something happen AFTER a "save", "commit", etc is completed on record #9991, because I need to see/touch that newly-inserted record AFTER Apex, Workflows, etc have done their thing.  *It's a recurring theme for me*.

---

A longer version of the example above:

- Record #9991 insert is performed...
- ... Apex does things
- ... Workflows do things
- Record #9991 is saved (committed) with OTHER fields populated by Apex/Workflows

Then:

- READ one of those fields after record #9991 is saved
- ... do something based on what is in those fields

Comment: As a side note:  I'm hoping I will eventually have an a-ha moment and be able to answer several Questions (my own and others) once I find what I'm trying to do, without resorting to Apex(!!!!) or Flows(!) if possible.